# How to evaluate a non-variable node in computation graph of Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would to evaluate a non-variable node in a computation graph of tensorflow. For example, there is a tf.concat operation which combine multiple variables from different subgraphs. Through tensorboard I find the node is called concat_0. Can I get the value of concat_0 with sess.run([])? I understand a variable can be found using tf.get_variable('variable_0') if I know the variable name is 'variable_0'. But how to retrieve a non-variable node by its name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is `<node name>:<endpoint>`. Typically nodes have only one output, so endpoint is 0.

Hence, you can value of `concat_0` node as

```
sess.run("concat_0:0")
```